# A beginner question: $ \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

What are the steps for working out $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$?

Is this correct  : $$\frac{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}x^2-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}1}{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}x-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}1}= \frac{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}x\cdot \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}x-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}1}{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}x-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}1}?$$

The limit of this function is $2$ but how to arrive at two using the limit laws?

Comment: Use mathjax, it makes it more readable

Comment: And you cannot take the limit of the numerator and denominator. Consider factorizing $x^2-1$

Comment: If you were to do what you started, you would end up with $\frac{1-1}{1-1}=\frac{0}{0}$ which is one of the "indeterminate forms", meaning that you have to look at it a bit more carefully as shown below.

Comment: Absolutely not.  Extending limits is almost never the way to go.  You have the limits of a bunch of divergent sequences and that'll never get you anywhere.  Instead note that as $x \rightarrow 1$, $x\ne 1$  can you divide $x-1$ out of $x^2-1$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution $1$**. One may write, for $x \neq1$,
$$
\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=x+1
$$ then let $x \to 1$:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x \to 1}(x+1)=1+1=2.
$$

**Solution $2$**. One may recall that, for any differentiable function $f$ near $a$, as $x \to a$, one has

> $$
> \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \to f'(a)
> $$

giving with $f(x)=x^2$, $f'(x)=2x$, $a=1$:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=2\times 1=2.
$$